# display database in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

***controller***

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def labstatus
    @labs = Lab.all
  end
end
```

***view***

```
<head>
<style>
table, th, td { border: 1px solid black;}
th, td { padding: 15px;}
</style>
</head>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Lab</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Comment</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @labs.each do |lab| %>
     <tr>
       <td><%= lab.Lab %></td>
       <td><%= lab.Status %></td>
       <td><%= lab.Comment %></td>
     </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>
```

***Model***

```
class Lab < ActiveRecord::Base
self.abstract_class = true
establish_connection(
  :adapter => "sqlite3",
  :host => "localhost",
  :database => "lab.db"
)
end
```

I am trying display the records from the lab database on my webpage in a table. I currently get this error when I navigate to the webpage where the records should be displayed `SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: : SELECT "".* FROM ""`. When I open the `lab.db` in sqlite3 the table and records are there. I have another database already set up in this rails app and am not sure if this is what is affecting my display. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try putting the `abstract_class` and `establish_connection` bits in a different base class (`class External < ActiveRecord::Base`), and then extend Lab from that: `class Lab < External`

Comment: I tried your suggestion @TaylorCampbell and no joy. I now get the error `SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: labs: SELECT "labs".* FROM "labs"`.